# Different output from $? running under bash -c

Tags: bash

Why do the following commands produce different output?

```
false ; echo $?
```

```
output: 1
```

```
bash -c "false ; echo $?"
```

```
output: 0
```

Both `echo $SHELL` and `bash -c "echo $SHELL"` return `/bin/bash` so I am not sure why the commands would differ in output.

Comment: Note that if you run `bash -c 'false; echo $?'; echo $?` you will get `1` and `0` output.  That's because `bash` exits with the status of the last command executed, and the `echo` succeeds.  Also `false; bash -c "false; echo $?"; echo $?` reports `1` and `0` — and if immediately followed by `bash -c "false; echo $?"` produces `0` as reported.

Comment: Note that `echo $$; bash -c "echo $$"` echoes the same value twice, whereas `echo $$; bash -c 'echo $$'` echoes two different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the argument to `bash -c` is in double quotes, the original shell performs variable substitution in it. So you're actually executing

```
bash -c "false; echo 0"
```

Change it to single quotes and you'll get the output you expect.

```
bash -c 'false; echo $?'
```

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: That's assuming the previous command (before `bash -c ...`) succeeded. If it failed, you'll see that exit status, e.g. `false; bash -c "true ; echo $?"` will print "1".

Comment: @GordonDavisson Since the OP got `0` output, it obviously did succeed.